# HOW TO ::: Create a "photo booth" web app / website?

Tags: web-applications

Recently I was asked the question if I could design a "photo booth" web app that someone could go to a website and if they're computer had a camera on it/ or if they're phone had a camera on it, it would pull up the camera and allow a photo to be taken and displayed on screen.  They would then be allowed to email the photo to themselves. That would be the base functionality of it.

I'm comfortable with HTML5, CSS3, and jQuery... Can I use those to create this software?

or...

Is their a "ready-made" software/plugin out there to allow me to grab the code and edit it accordingly to fit the project specifications?

If anyone has some advice I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to support HTML5 browsers only, check out HTML5 Webcam Toy http://neave.com/webcam/html5/

I believe Adobe Flash can also take advantage of a user's camera if you want to support older browsers.

Comment: awesome! I'll check that link out.

Comment: Looks like HTML5 can also do this via getUserMedia and Canvas: www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/06/html5/filtering-a-webcam-using-getusermedia-and-html5-canvas
Filtering a webcam using getUserMedia and HTML5 Canvas.